# Юнит тестирование

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

изучая JUnit появился вопрос как правильно писать юнит тесты. Сейчас на своих учебных проектах стараюсь писать как можно больше тестов, но понимаю что большинство из них в настоящих проектах  будут избыточны и только мешать, так как перегружают мозг количеством кода.

Так вот вопрос как понять когда тесты действительно нужны, как писать качественные тесты, как писать тесты для еще не реализованных(не написанных) методов.

Answer (score 1):

Читаю книгу `Чистый код`, автор `Роберт Мартин`. Он утверждает что 100% кода должны быть покрыты тестами. Даже разработку он видит через написание тестов, то есть сначала тесты пишутся потом код(**TDD**  test-driven development).

Для интеграций реализуется шаблон адаптер, и для интерфейса делается тестовый класс.

Качественные тесты являются независимыми друг от друга, и покрывают большую часть программы, чтобы можно было быстро проверить код.

В реальной разработке тестов чем больше, тем проще новому разработчику понять что там происходит и начать участвовать в разработке. Но те кто ставят задачи как правило не хотят слишком много времени тратить на тесты.

В учебных проектах тесты на мой взгляд должны быть, но не много, просто для изучения(какие тесты бывают).